# How to configure OneSignal Push on ionic so that push notification only opens app mainpage

Tags: android, ionic-framework, gcm-network-manager

I have installed onesignal push on my ionic app, it worked well but when i send web push and by clicking on that specific notification on my Android device it takes me to external browser to open that notification.

Now I want what ever type of notification i will send from one signal to my app it should only open app, not browser not more than that.

Answer (score 0):

You must omit setting a Launch URL on the OneSignal dashboard or the `url` field if you are using the REST API. You will need to send two different notifications if you need to still direct the user to a specific URL for your web push users.

Answer (score 0):

For opening a link with your app, you can use the custom-url-scheme cordova plugin . This enables you to open your app with an external link like testapp://path?foo=bar . [Here is the link](http://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme)